# Почему слик слайдер растягивает блоки?

Tags: html, css, slider-slick.js

При указании ширины самого слайдера происходит следующая ситуация. Слайдер как-будто не хочет становится по центру.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.team {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 163px;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #FAFAFA, #FAFAFA), #FAE6F5;
}

.team__inner {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.team__subtitle {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.slick-slide {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.team__block-info {
  padding-left: 45px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.team__block-title {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.name {
  padding-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  color: #000000;
}

.name-title {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #000;
}

.expiriens__item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.expiriens__item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.expiriens__item-img {
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.slick-next__img {
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.slick-list {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Лента слайдов */

.slick-track {
  display: flex;
}


/* Слайд */

.slick-slide {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden
}


/* Слайд активный (показывается) */

.slick-slide.slick-active {}


/* Слайд основной */

.slick-slide.slick-current {}


/* Слайд по центру */

.slick-slide.slick-center {}


/* Клонированный слайд */

.slick-slide.slick-cloned {}


/* Стрелка */

.slick-arrow {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  bottom: -68px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slick-arrow>img {
  padding-left: 15px;
}


/* Стрелка влево */

.slick-arrow.slick-prev {
  right: 13%;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
}


/* Стрелка вправо */

.slick-arrow.slick-next {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #96317D;
}


/* Стрелка не активная */

.slick-arrow.slick-disabled {}


/* Точки (булиты) */

.slick-dots {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: start;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -70px;
  left: 5px;
}

.slick-dots li {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}


/* Активная точка */

.slick-dots li.slick-active {
  border: 2px solid #96317D;
  border-radius: 100%;
}


/* Элемент точки */

.slick-dots li button {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-image: url(../images/dot.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section id="team" class="team">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="team__inner">
      <p class="team__subtitle plum">
        В нашем штате 37 сотрудников
      </p>
      <h2 class="team__title title">
        Мы большая команда профессионалов
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">
      <div class="slick-slide">
        <img class="team__block-img" src="images/Man-1.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="team__block-info">
          <div class="name">
            <h3 class="team__block-title name-title">
              Александр Федулов
            </h3>
            <p class="team__block-text">
              Ремонтник
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="expiriens">
            <div class="expiriens__item">
              <img class="expiriens__item-img" src="images/check.svg" alt="">
              <p class="expiriens__item-text plum">398 ремонтных работ</p>
            </div>
            <div class="expiriens__item">
              <img class="expiriens__item-img" src="images/check.svg" alt="">
              <p class="expiriens__item-text plum">3 года в Fixper</p>
            </div>
            <div class="expiriens__item">
              <img class="expiriens__item-img" src="images/check.svg" alt="">
              <p class="expiriens__item-text plum">Рейтинг Fixper 4,5</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slick-slide">
        <img class="team__block-img" src="images/Man-2.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="team__block-info">
          <div class="name">
            <h3 class="team__block-title name-title">
              Александр Федулов
            </h3>
            <p class="team__block-text">
              Ремонтник
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="expiriens">
            <div class="expiriens__item">
              <img class="expiriens__item-img" src="images/check.svg" alt="">
              <p class="expiriens__item-text plum">398 ремонтных работ</p>
            </div>
            <div class="expiriens__item">
              <img class="expiriens__item-img" src="images/check.svg" alt="">
              <p class="expiriens__item-text plum">3 года в Fixper</p>
            </div>
            <div class="expiriens__item">
              <img class="expiriens__item-img" src="images/check.svg" alt="">
              <p class="expiriens__item-text plum">Рейтинг Fixper 4,5</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slick-slide">
        <img class="team__block-img" src="images/Man-3.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="team__block-info">
          <div class="name">
            <h3 class="team__block-title name-title">
              Александр Федулов
            </h3>
            <p class="team__block-text">
              Ремонтник
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="expiriens">
            <div class="expiriens__item">
              <img class="expiriens__item-img" src="images/check.svg" alt="">
              <p class="expiriens__item-text plum">398 ремонтных работ</p>
            </div>
            <div class="expiriens__item">
              <img class="expiriens__item-img" src="images/check.svg" alt="">
              <p class="expiriens__item-text plum">3 года в Fixper</p>
            </div>
            <div class="expiriens__item">
              <img class="expiriens__item-img" src="images/check.svg" alt="">
              <p class="expiriens__item-text plum">Рейтинг Fixper 4,5</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slick-slide">
        <img class="team__block-img" src="images/Man-4.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="team__block-info">
          <div class="name">
            <h3 class="team__block-title name-title">
              Александр Федулов
            </h3>
            <p class="team__block-text">
              Ремонтник
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="expiriens">
            <div class="expiriens__item">
              <img class="expiriens__item-img" src="images/check.svg" alt="">
              <p class="expiriens__item-text plum">398 ремонтных работ</p>
            </div>
            <div class="expiriens__item">
              <img class="expiriens__item-img" src="images/check.svg" alt="">
              <p class="expiriens__item-text plum">3 года в Fixper</p>
            </div>
            <div class="expiriens__item">
              <img class="expiriens__item-img" src="images/check.svg" alt="">
              <p class="expiriens__item-text plum">Рейтинг Fixper 4,5</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slick-slide">
        <img class="team__block-img" src="images/Man-5.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="team__block-info">
          <div class="name">
            <h3 class="team__block-title name-title">
              Александр Федулов
            </h3>
            <p class="team__block-text">
              Ремонтник
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="expiriens">
            <div class="expiriens__item">
              <img class="expiriens__item-img" src="images/check.svg" alt="">
              <p class="expiriens__item-text plum">398 ремонтных работ</p>
            </div>
            <div class="expiriens__item">
              <img class="expiriens__item-img" src="images/check.svg" alt="">
              <p class="expiriens__item-text plum">3 года в Fixper</p>
            </div>
            <div class="expiriens__item">
              <img class="expiriens__item-img" src="images/check.svg" alt="">
              <p class="expiriens__item-text plum">Рейтинг Fixper 4,5</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</section>
```

JS

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slider').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        dots: true,
        prevArrow: "<button type='button' class='slick-prev slick-arrow'>Назад</button>",
        nextArrow: "<button type='button' class='slick-next slick-arrow'>Далее<img src='images/Arrow-purp.svg' alt=''></button>",
        responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 1250,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    slidesToScroll: 2,
                }
            }
            
        ]
    });

    $('.slider__two').slick({
        infinite: true,
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        dots: true,
        prevArrow: "<button type='button' class='slick-prev slick-arrow'>Назад</button>",
        nextArrow: "<button type='button' class='slick-next slick-arrow'>Далее<img src='images/Arrow-purp.svg' alt=''></button>",
    });
```

Comment: Всё зависит от настройки слайдера. ПРиведите пример Вашей настройки

Comment: Исправил. В конце вопроса настройки слайдера